# Javascript getting xlink:href from XPath using document.evaluate

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, nodes, element

Hey all I am having the worst time trying to figure out why my **XPath** code below is not able to find the **Image tag** and the **HREF link** that goes with it within my document.

The **XPath** (full) looks like this:

> //html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/a/div/svg/g/descendant::image[starts-with(@href,'https://')]

The javascript code I am using is:

```
function checking(Path) {
   const nodes = document.evaluate(Path, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
   const result = {
       Data: []
   };
   let attr = nodes.iterateNext();
   result.Data.push({ href: attr});
   return JSON.stringify(result);
}
console.log(checking("//html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/a/div/svg/g/descendant::image[starts-with(@href,'https://')]"));
```

And the **HTML** that I am looking through to get said image **Xlink:HREF**:

```
<body class="">
  <div id="" style="">
    <div>
      <div class="">
        <div class="">
          <div class="">
            <div class="">
              <div class="">
                <div class="">
                  <div class="">
                    <div class="">
                      <div class="" role="5ma">
                        <div class="">
                          <div class="">
                            <div class="">
                              <div>
                                <div class="">
                                  <div class="">
                                    <div class="">
                                      <a aria-label="" class="" href="https://www.this.com/link/is/not/needed" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="">
                                          <svg aria-label="" class="" data-visualcompletion="ignore-dynamic" role="img" style="height: 168px; width: 168px;">
                                            <g mask="url(#)">
                                              <image x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2021/seasonal-holidays-2021-6753651837109324-6752733080595603-cst.gif" style="height: 168px; width: 168px;"></image>
                                              <circle class="" cx="8" cy="4" r="4"></circle>
                                            </g>
                                          </svg>
                                        </div>
                                      </a>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I keep getting **NULL** for the **output** for some reason? And here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/pg68zr07/2/) to visually test it.

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "href": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone have a clue as to why I am?

**UPDATE 1**

[image]

Checking the "offical" xPath to my project comes out to be this:

> //                        html/body/div[1](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/pg68zr07/2/)/div/div[1](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/pg68zr07/2/)/div/div[3](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/gq2jabxc/)/div/div/div[1](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/pg68zr07/2/)/div[1](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/pg68zr07/2/)/div/div/div[1](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/pg68zr07/2/)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhIRf.png)/div/div/div/div[1](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/pg68zr07/2/)/div/div/svg/g/image

Which I change the latest fiddle to reflect what @bigless suggested in his fiddle but still get null.

Newest [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/gq2jabxc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to @Jack Fleeting answer (skipping all those divs just for example) with xlink:href selector:

```
string(//*[name() = 'svg']/*[name()='g']//*[name()='image' and starts-with(@*[name()='xlink:href'],'https://')]/@*[name()='xlink:href'])
```

This will extract just attribute value as a string (first occurence)

Comment: Tried your example @bigless and there was an error of **Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[name() = 'svg']/*[name()='g']//*[name()='image' and starts-with(@*[name()='xlink:href'],'https://')]/@*[name()='xlink:href'])' is not a valid XPath expression.** using it like so **let comeback = checking("//*[name() = 'svg']/*[name()='g']//*[name()='image' and starts-with(@*[name()='xlink:href'],'https://')]/@*[name()='xlink:href']");**

Comment: @StealthRT try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncbguowy/2/). It's without string function to make it as close as possible to your fiddle

Comment: Well I spoke too soon. I get this error when I implement it into the read code: **Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']//*[name()='image' and starts-with(@*[name()='xlink:href'],'https://')]/@*[name()='xlink:href'])' is not a valid XPath expression.**

Comment: @StealthRT You got extra ')' at the end of expression (copy paste mistake;) or you copied string function from here. Try xpath from fiddle.

Comment: Hum doesn't seem to be that? Look at my OP for an updated screen shot of what I am seeing on my end.

Comment: @StealthRT Guess that you got one more div or something like that.. This is [shortcuted version](https://jsfiddle.net/ncbguowy/3/) without those divs. Also you want nodeValue, not whole Attr object.

Comment: Yep, must have been an extra **Div** that was causing it issues. Seems to be working now with that shortcut version. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

First, you have a problem with namespaces and [Deprecated XLink URL reference attributes](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/linking.html#XLinkRefAttrs).

Second, in

```
result.Data.push({
    href: attr
  });
```

you should `push` the node value of the attribute:

```
result.Data.push({
    href: attr.nodeValue
  });
```

Finally, because of the namespace issue, and to simplify the xpath expression, change your `comeback` to

```
var comeback = checking("//*[local-name()='image'][starts-with(./@href,'https://')]/@href");
```

[And it should work as in this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/yewaok8g/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jack but you seem to have taken out the **xlink:href** in your jsfiddle. I'm not able to rename that to just href and therefore your example code does not work - error of **Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nodeValue')**.